# Custom UICollectionViewLayout (Passbook UI replica) - disable fade animations for cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, passbook

I'm trying to recreate the passbook UI using a collection view with a custom layout.
So far so good, but there's this thing I can't seem to find a solution for.

Problem: When I click on a cell I want it to move up to the top of the screen (content offset of the cv). Most of the cells don't have a problem with this and they perform as such. However, when the selected cell is near the bottom of the screen, there's no moving at all... just a fade-out and fade-in.

To achieve this animation, I embedded the layout subclass' invalidateLayout in an animation block to be performed by UIView. No matter how high or low I set the time interval, the duration is still the same, and so no effect on the fade-in fade-out behaviour.

I'll paste here the methods that I believe to need to be modified and also a link to a video on youtube. Hopefully, someone can find a solution for this >_<".

YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xIL-fFUcJo

Code: http://pastebin.com/QKLKGwdN

Comment: If you are looking for a way to make this happen without UICollectionView happily I can share what I have done?